# What are examples of $|{x_1,x_2,x_3}|=1$?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

This question is from an old assignment for which I have the answer to, but I am confused by,

A computer outputs a hexadecimal code consisting of a string $x_1\, x_2 \, x_3\, x_4\, x_5$ of $5$ symbols, each of
which is one of $\{0, 1, . . . , 9, A, B, C, D, E, F\}$. Assume that the output is chosen uniformly at
random from among all codes of this form. Let $A$ be the event that 
$|\{x_1, x_3, x_4\}| = 1$ and $B$ be
the event that $|\{x_1, x_3, x_4\}|= 3$

Find $\Pr(A)$

how can you have a magnitude of a set equal $1$ if the set in question has $3$ elements within? Case to observe $|\{x_1, x_3, x_4\}| = 1$.

I understand there are $16^5$ possibilities overall, what I am concerned with is how would you identify the possibilities with magnitude being $1$?

Comment: Please note I know the answer is 1/256, what I don't know is why

Comment: The set is defined by 3 symbols but they can all be equal, and then the set has really only cardinality 1. So your question about A is really another way of saying "what is the probability that x1=x3=x4".

Comment: so in short is {x1,x3,x4} independent of the whole set? do I treat it independently?

Comment: $\{2,3,3\}=\{2,3\}$, hope that explains it. It seems you are mostly confused about the fact that a set contains no duplicates. Whatever you put in a set, only lives there in one copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x_1, x_3, x_4\}$ has cardinality $1$ if all its elements are identical and it has at least one element

Assuming independence, if you know $x_1$ (which could be any of the possibilities) then you need $x_3$ to be the same, with probability $\frac1{16}$, and  $x_4$ to be the same, also with probability $\frac1{16}$

so the probability that all three are the same is $\frac1{16^2}$

Comment: so if  $|\{x_1, x_3, x_4\}|=|{2,2,2}|$ then the cardinality would just be 1?

Comment: $\{2,2,2\} = \{2\}$ so $|\{2,2,2\}|=|\{2\}|=1$